# Prevent backspace button from navigating back to previous XPage

Tags: jquery, dojo, xpages, lotus-domino

In my XPages application, I have noticed that whenever I hit the backspace key (without an input field having focus), the application returns to the previous XPage. How can I disable this behavior? I believe this is possible with JQuery and / or Dojo but am unsure how to add the code to an XPage? Also, could preventing this behavior have any impact on performance?

Comment: Don't brake the back button. It is an essential capability of how users expect their browsers to behave. Adjust your flow to be ok with that

Comment: I'm referring to the backspace button

Comment: Uuups. Sorry for that

Comment: Backspace = keyboard shortcut for back button (at least in Chrome and Firefox on Windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dojo version to prevent Esc to close xPage tab in client. Guess you can use something similar for your problem as well.

```
<xp:eventHandler
        event="onClientLoad"
        submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[dojo.addOnLoad( function(){ 
 dojo.connect( document, 'keydown', function(e){  
         if(e.keyCode === 27){ dojo.stopEvent(e); }        
 });
});]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have decided to use dojo rather than jquery as loading the jquery library could have a negative impact on performance.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem using the following code (after I had added jquery to the WEB-INF folder):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<xp:eventHandler event="onClientLoad" submit="false">
    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[

$(document).keypress(function(e) {
var elid = $(document.activeElement).is("input, textarea") ;

if (e.keyCode === 8 && !elid) {
    if(e.ctrlKey) {
        window.history.back()
    }
    else {
        alert("Navigating with Backspace has been disabled. Use CTRL + Backspace if you want to go back to the previous page (and lose any unsaved changes).");
        return false;
    }
}
});
]]></xp:this.script>
</xp:eventHandler>
```

It would be nice to have a solution for this in dojo also!

EDIT: Here is the dojo version of this solution -

```
dojo.addOnLoad( function(){dojo.connect( document, 'keypress', function(e){

    var activeElementId = document.activeElement.tagName;  

     if(e.keyCode === 8 && activeElementId != "INPUT" && activeElementId != "TEXTAREA"){ 

     if(e.ctrlKey) {
        window.history.back()
    }
     else {
        alert(messageValue);
        dojo.stopEvent(e);
    }

      }  });
```

});

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```js
$(document).on('keydown', function(e){
    var kc = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if(kc == 8 && document.activeElement === 'body'){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' />
```

---

This solution checks if the active element is `body` then prevent the default behavior of the <kbd>backspace</kbd> key with cheking if the key pressed is the backspace key which has the keyCode of `8`.

Comment: can you tell me how to specifically add this code to an XPAge? I?ve tried <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
 $(document).on('keydown', function(e){
    var kc = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if(kc == 8 && document.activeElement === 'body'){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
 });
 ]]>
 </script> but it will not compile

Comment: @TonyGuiheen this is not a correct way of writing a  js code to a script block. if you apply a `src` attribute on a script tag then anything written in the script block `<script src='jquery.js'>Will omit this beacuse of src attribute.</script>`

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to add this code?